Is there a standard term for a generator of maximal cyclic subgroup?
Is there a standard term for a group element that generates a maximal cyclic subgroup? Here "cyclic subgroup" means a subgroup generated by one element, and could be infinite. "Maximal cyclic subgroup" means a cyclic subgroup that is not a proper subgroup of another cyclic subgroup.
By analogy with the generators of the multiplicative group of a finite field I'm inclined to call such elements "primitive elements", but I'm interested in finding out whether another term is more standard.
Example 1: The dihedral group of the octagon. The group has $16$ elements and $12$ of them generate a maximal cyclic subgroup. If $\rho$ is a $45^\circ$ rotation, then each of $\rho$, $\rho^3$, $\rho^5$, and $\rho^7$ generates the maximal cycle subgroup of order $8$. Each of the eight reflections generates a maximal cyclic subgroup of order $2$.
Example 2: The modular group, $\operatorname{PSL}(2,\mathbf{Z})$. The element
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
19 & 36\\
-9 & -17
\end{bmatrix}
$$
generates an infinite cyclic subgroup, but not a maximal one since
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
19 & 36\\
-9 & -17
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4\\
-1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^9.
$$
The only other element that generates the same maximal cyclic subgroup as does
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4\\
-1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & -4\\
1 & 3
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 4\\
-1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
$$
Example 3: The group $(\mathbf{Q},+)$ has no such elements since it has no maximal cyclic subgroups. (It is a divisible goup.)
Example 4: The quaternion group $\mathrm{Q}_8$. There are three maximal cyclic subgroups, each of order $4$. These three subgroups have pairwise nontrivial intersection. One is generated by $i$ or $-i$, one by $j$ or $-j$, the third by $k$ or $-k$. Hence there are six such elements.

I do not think there is standard terminology, but "primitive" is a reasonable choice (unless your group is free, in which case "primitive" would mean something else).

@MoisheKohan Thanks for alerting me to the use of the term "primitive" in the context of free groups. I suspect you are right about there being no standard term.
